# Debugging give 404 error when running on local IIS

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, visual-studio-2017

"unable to start debugging on the web server the remote server returned an error 404".
this is the error that the debugger gives me 
the debugger works on IIS Express, but never on the local IIS

Is anyone aware of a solution to this? Am i overlooking something?

Thanks!

Comment: When hosting on IIS and receiving an error code, check its substatus first https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0

Comment: Error 404 is Server or Page not found.  What is the URL?

Comment: Do you mean you have used remote debug to debug the local IIS or remote server? If you debug the application on IIS by using VS debug.Could you please post the project's property debug setting? Besides, I suggest you could firstly check your site which hosted on the IIS is working well(You could access the page directly in the browser).

Comment: @jdweng 404 not found 
url: http://localhost/ProjectName

Comment: Localhost definition varies from machine to machine.  You can see what is being used from cmd.exe >ping localhost.  In most cases the localhost is defined in the file C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts.  The IP address 127.0.0.1 is the loopback address and some machine use the IP address of the host and others the loopback address.  Then some machines have more than one IP addrtess.  The specification for IP says every machine must have a loopback address.  So I would try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the solution was just do a check if the site where I was trying to debug was running propperly; In my case, the `Default Web Site` was stopped, and I had to restart it

[image: Check if the IIS target site is running]